# Reset value of dropdown list with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I need to reset the value of a dropdown list with a radio button. So when a certain radio button is selected, it will reset a specific dropdown list to the default selected="selected" option.

How can this be done with js and css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that this is the code for your first element

```
<select id=foo>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

your radio button should be something like this:

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('foo').value = '';" type="radio" name="bar" value="bar">
```

The value under the onclick event needs to be replaced with the default value for your dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

This should reset your dropdown to the first option.
Here's the markup

```
<select id=foo>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input onclick="resetFoo();" type="radio" name="bar" value="bar">
```

Here's the jQuery.

```
function doSomething {
    $("#foo option:first").attr("selected", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('select').selectedIndex = 0;

<input type="radio" onchange="doSomething()" />
```

Comment: how would I call this with an onClick function using a radio button?